# What is this code doing?

Tags: python

```
>>> string1, string2, string3 = '', 'Trondheim', 'Hammer Dance'
>>> non_null = string1 or string2 or string3
>>> non_null
'Trondheim'
```

This from the python tutorial of this [page](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/tutorial/datastructures.html), I don't understand the 2nd line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demonstrating a) operator short-circuiting and b) the fact that, in Python, logical operators can take and return non-`bool` values:

```
string1 or string2 or string3 # is the same as
(string1 or string2) or string3
# string1 or string2 is '' or 'Trondheim', and as
# '' is logically False, this results in 'Trondheim'
# 'Trondheim' or string3 is short-circuited and never evaluated,
# because a non-empty string is logically True
```

Answer (score 7):

The python `or` operator can be defined as [1]:

```
x or y : if x is false, then y, else x
```

When you do `string1 or string2`, `string1` is an empty string, which Python translates as `False` (side node: some programming languages do this, others don't), so by the definition above it evaluates to the value of `string2`. When it then does `(result of 'string1 or string2') or string3`, `string2` is not an empty string, and so does not equate to `False`, and so it evaluates to `string2`.

[1] http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/boolean.html

Answer (score 2):

It simply returns you the first non empty string 'Trondheim' and is the same as:

```
non_null = (string1 or string2) or string3
```

Or:

```
if not string1:
    string3 if not string2 else string2
else:
    string1
```

Answer (score 1):

If uses short circuit boolean evaluation to find the first non-null string in the list.  For strings, the empty string `''` evaluates to `False` and everything other string is regarded as a `True` value.

Sections 5.1 and 5.2 from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) tell you all you need to know to understand this.

In particular:

> ```
> x or y       if x is false, then y, else x
> ```
>
> This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is False.

Answer (score 1):

It just checks which string is not null and passes it to a non_null variable. string1 is empty, so the string2 can be used.